# iOS Application Background Fetch

Tags: ios

I am iOS developer and currently working on a Project which needs to hit an API after every 1 min in background and I am unable to do that. Is there any solution for it ? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it not work?

Comment: I have tried beginBackgroundTaskWithName for it

Comment: I have turned the background fetch On in Capabilities and even my background fetch function is called but Api is returning time out every time. Moreover, the fundtion is not called every 1 minute .

Comment: @ZeMoon do you have any solution for it.

Comment: you can use alamofire for that

Comment: Please update your question with these details along with the code for scheduling the background fetch. Someone should be able to come along and help you.

Comment: I am using this function for background fetch

**-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
 
self.hitAPiToGetResponse()

  }**


I am calling the function in this to hit api , and it returns error :- "Request time out" if the application is in background or killed

Comment: '  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:5.0];'

Comment: @dineshsharma I have already used alamofire for it but it is not giving response.

Answer (score 0):

Short: Not possible

Long:
The most precious resource on a mobile device is the battery power. It has to be sparsely used.

Therefore no application in its sandbox is allowed to run infinite or get waked every minute.

Whatever the usecase for contacting the server is, the process has to be redesigned to fit into a mobile scenario. The options are push, opportunistic background fetch or using background sessions for talking to the server. However none of this options will guarantee a wake up every minute.

Comment: @heige Becker thanks for you precious answer, how silent notification will help in this case ?

Comment: Rather than polling every minute your server should send a push when it has new data. If your app is in the foreground then you *could* fetch data every minute but it isn't typically the best approach. If your app is in the background then it is unlikely that fetching data every minute is a good use of resources.